# create report with reportviewer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reportviewer, report

I want to create report using report viewer in asp.net. 
I want to create it from runtime page  load with sql query like select columnname from tablename.
I want to use datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you know how to fetch your data from your database, and how to put a Reportviewer object on your page.

then you can put something like this in your page_load

```
        var report = new LocalReport();
        report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("NameOfDatasourceInReport", TheDataTable));
        report.ReportEmbeddedResource = "NameOfYourReport.With.NameSpace.rdlc";
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport = report;
```